# Difference between Hand direction vs palm Normal

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion

What is the difference between Hand.[Direction](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/unity/api/Leap.Hand.html#csharpclass_leap_1_1_hand_1a3760f0d03c577bd8a45779cf3f9a46a8) and Hand.[PalmNormal](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/unity/api/Leap.Hand.html#csharpclass_leap_1_1_hand_1aef5d40d014a9385fd434bb3b67013967)?
in the documentation, both methods have mentioned that "The direction is expressed as a unit vector pointing in the same direction as the directed line from the palm position to the fingers." what is the exact direction of the palm? is palm normal the normal vector of the direction?

Comment: Have you tried using `Debug.DrawRay` to find out what it is? What you say sounds right, that direction would be along the fingers and palmnormal be the vector sticking out of the palm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hand.Direction vs Hand.PalmNormal**

Hand.Direction is like if you took a pencil and bridged the distance from the middle of your palm towards your fingers. Hand.PalmNormal would be if you took a pencil and put the eraser end of it flat on your palm, ignoring anything the fingers are doing.

To see for yourself, there is a [demo](http://jaanga.github.io/gestification/cookbook/leap-direction-vs-normal/r2/leap-direction-vs-normal.html) you can check out. Also, here is a graphical depiction:

[image]